# What is this type of navigation is called?

Tags: navigation, terminology

I came across the term for this style of navigation on a site but I failed to save the url. Anyone know what this type of navigation is called?

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for the name of the navigation style (which is a user mode)? Or for the specific piece of UI (which is a bunch of pixels)?

Comment: I'm going to go with Antid's answer below. It looks like a regular ol' navbar. Does it appear on the top of the screen? The layout of it looks like a Button Group: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-groups

Comment: There was a specific term used in the article "something something picker" which is being used in the UX community.

Answer (score 2):

If the purpose is to serve as navigation header for your site, this is called Navigation Bar. http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

Answer (score -1):

I believe it's called a ["scope bar"](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/Bars.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH12-SW1) according to Apples HIG. I suppose it depends on the context in which it's used.

Comment: A scope bar implies that the options are different scopes on a single data set. I expect that Work and Play could be two scopes on one set of data, but Profile, Notebook, and especially the Twitter icon seem to be unrelated.